# javascript get URL parameter and

Tags: javascript

I have a URL http://www.test.com/us/abc/

my CMS only accept html and javascript

Is it possible using javascript to get this current url. and then get "us" parameter and put it in if else statement?

If "us" detected, echo out "US website".
If "ca" detected, echo out "Canada website".

Thanks

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
window.location.href;
</script>
```

Comment: You can split the url by '/' then get the third item in splitted array.

Comment: What CMS are you using? Does it not offer access to the URL and its parts in the template through some sort template language like Liquid? Or are you providing data to the template in which case you can't use the templating language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const country = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]
if (country === 'us') console.log('US website')
if (country === 'ca') console.log('Canada website')
```

You can find more on location API at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).